# Imported a file using maftools in R studio

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am trying to import my variant file in R studio with all the required maf columns

'Chr Start End Ref Alt Gene.refGene GeneDetail.refGene ExonicFunc.refGene AAChange.refGene Tumor_Sample_Barcode Func.refGene'

using this code:

```
var.annovar2 <- system.file("extdata", "mutation.hg19_multianno.txt", package = "maftools")
```

But imported file is empty.

what am I missing?

Comment: There is no file "mutation.hg19_multianno.txt" in maftools extdata folder, maybe you would need "variants.hg19_multianno.txt" ?

Comment: I have never used package `maftools` but that file is not a package data file, you probably want [`read.maf`](https://rdrr.io/bioc/maftools/man/read.maf.html).

Comment: Welcome to SO. 1. maftools has a file "variants.hg19_multianno.txt" but not "mutation.hg19_multianno.txt" (see [here](https://rdrr.io/bioc/maftools/f/)). 2. `system.file` does not read the file. It only creates a full path to the file. And it returns an empty string if the file does not exist (which it does not). So everything works as designed.